# Google Cloud Storage auth token in React Native

Tags: react-native, jwt, google-cloud-storage, auth-token

With [Google Could Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload) my core problem is AUTH_TOKEN in required Authorization header.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/myBucket/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_FILE]
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]

[JPEG_DATA]
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt) it's explained how to obtain the auth token (OAuth 2.0 for Service Accounts).

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiI3NjEzMjY3OTgwNjktcjVtbGpsbG4xcmQ0bHJiaGc3NWVmZ2lncDM2bTc4ajVAZGV2ZWxvcGVyLmdzZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC5jb20iLCJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdvb2dsZWFwaXMuY29tL2F1dGgvcHJlZGljdGlvbiIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9vL29hdXRoMi90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTMyODU3MzM4MSwiaWF0IjoxMzI4NTY5NzgxfQ.ixOUGehweEVX_UKXv5BbbwVEdcz6AYS-6uQV6fGorGKrHf3LIJnyREw9evE-gs2bmMaQI5_UbabvI4k-mQE4kBqtmSpTzxYBL1TCd7Kv5nTZoUC1CmwmWCFqT9RE6D7XSgPUh_jF1qskLa2w0rxMSjwruNKbysgRNctZPln7cqQ
```

The request (above) requires the **assertion** param, which is **JWT** generated using RS256 (below).

```
{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.
{
"iss":"761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
"aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
"exp":1328554385,
"iat":1328550785
}.
[signature bytes]
```

I [have problem generating JWT in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981899/making-crypto-work-in-react-native) using `react-native-jwt`.

Has anyone got around the authorization for Google Could Storage, while using React Native?